# Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "sa" does not exist

Tags: c#, sql-server

We met a problem: we created one website with c#. There is one button on the website to connect to SQL Server database, and call one stored procedure to perform the task.

Our user is granted execute privilege for the stored procedure. However, when user click the button on the website, there will show the error as below. Only if the user has the Admin privilege on the server, where the database and c# application stand, the button works fine.

The error message is:

> Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "sa" does
>   not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do
>   not have permission.

The c# code, which triggers the error, is:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Could some one help me out?

I tried to assign the standard privilege for the user on the server, but it didn't work. And assign user has the ownership of the database, where the stored procedure and related tables exist, also didn't work.

Comment: can you show your connectionstring

Comment: Was the SQL Server instance installed with mixed mode authentication? `sa` is not a Windows principal.

Comment: Is the Id the web application's app pool uses authorized to get to the database?